# How to select rows based on a column that is not a primary key

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a table t1 (id, source, info, contact_date), id and source are primary key, for example

```
id    source    info    contact_date
01   s1             …         2013-3-1
01   s2             …         2013-3-1
01   s3             …         2013-2-28
…
```

I want to write a query, the result table will be like either

```
id    source    info    contact_date
01   s1             …         2013-3-1
```

Or

```
id    source    info    contact_date
01   s2             …         2013-3-1
```

You may suggest to change the primary key to id and contact_date, but I can’t, I have to keep the original design. Currently I have following query

```
select 
    t1.id, t1.source, t1.info, t1.contact_date 
from t1 
join
    (select id, max(contact_date) as contact_date 
     from t1 
     group by id) t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.contact_date = t2.contact_date
```

But the result table is below which is not what I want.

```
id    source    info    contact_date
01   s1             …         2013-3-1
01   s2             …         2013-3-1
```

Any idea?

Comment: It's to determine what you're asking. As best I can tell, you want only records from a single source returned? Can you clarify?

Comment: I do not care about what the source will be in the result table, either one s1, or s2 is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Ranking Function` on this.

```
SELECT  id, source, info, contact_date
FROM
        (
            SELECT  id, source, info, contact_date,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                    (PARTITION BY ID 
                     ORDER BY contact_date DESC) rn
            FROM    t1 
        ) x
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f050/2)